# Sorting information to output list

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and I thought it would be great to start with something a bit simple but useful for me and my girlfriend.

I would like to create a shopping list program that will take my items that I input into the textbox and then sort them based on defined groups. Then output that information in an easy to read list already categorized for easy shopping.

My question is this; How do I sort information that I put into a rich textbox? I have two rich textboxes and I would like to input information into one and then output that information to the other but have it sorted to my preferences.

Thank you in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to group them, I would suggest creating a small `GroceryItem` like this:

```
class  GroceryItem 
{
    GroceryItem(string category, string name) {
        Category = category;
        ItemName = name;
    }

    public string Category {get;set;}
    public string ItemName {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can easily parse from your first text box the items. Let's assume they look like this:

> Vegies, Tomato
>   Meat, Lamb
>   Vegies, Potato
>   Meat, Chicken

Just read them all, split on `,` to get 2 parts for each, and create a new `GroceryItem`:

```
List<CategoryItem> shoppingList = new List<CategoryItem>();
foreach (var line in your_lines_collection)
{
    var parts = some_line.Split(',');
    shoppingList.Add(new GroceryITem(parts[0],parts[1]));
}
```

And last, but not least, once you have a list of those (`shoppingList`), you can use linq to sort to your heart content. Here's an example:

```
List<GroceryItem> shoppingList = new List<GroceryItem>();

List<string> groceries = new List<string>(){"veg, pot", "veg, tom", "meat, chicken", "meat, veal"};
foreach (var line in groceries)
{
    var parts = line.Split(',');
    shoppingList.Add(new GroceryItem(parts[0],parts[1]));
}

var sorted_list_by_ItemName = 
    from item in shoppingList
    orderby item.ItemName
    group  item by item.Category into groups
    select groups
        ;

foreach (var gr in sorted_list_by_ItemName)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("[{0}] :", gr.Key);
    foreach (var it in gr)
        Console.Out.WriteLine("    {0}", it);
}
```

This will output:

```
[meat] :
    meat ,  chicken
    meat ,  veal
[veg] :
    veg ,  pot
    veg ,  tom
```

You then can just print this on your other textbox, or work with it as you wish :)

---

As per comments, here's the whole code for a console, just paste it into your visual studio, and it should work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<GroceryItem> shoppingList = new List<GroceryItem>();

        List<string> groceries = new List<string>() { "veg, pot", "veg, tom", "meat, chicken", "meat, veal" };
        foreach (var line in groceries)
        {
            var parts = line.Split(',');
            shoppingList.Add(new GroceryItem(parts[0], parts[1]));
        }

        var sorted_list_by_ItemName =
            from item in shoppingList
            orderby item.ItemName
            group item by item.Category into groups
            select groups;


        foreach (var gr in sorted_list_by_ItemName)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("[{0}] :", gr.Key);
            foreach (var it in gr)
                Console.Out.WriteLine("    {0}", it);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class GroceryItem
    {
        public GroceryItem(string category, string name)
        {
            Category = category;
            ItemName = name;
        }

        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Category + " , " + ItemName;
        }
    }

}
```

To avoid an ongoing ping pong, if you have another question, just open a new one (if it's relevant). Otherwise, you can upvote,downvote, and mark as answered if this answered your question. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess my level of programming is still too low for even this T_T

I like the way you've put this though and this is pretty much what i'm looking for. Reading it, this makes sense to me, however, after trying to put this into VS2012 it just give me errors.

Comment: Maybe ... but 1. You need to start somewhere. 2. this compiles and works, so you can play with it, and learn from it. 3. that's the only way we learn, looking at things we don't know yet :)

Comment: Yes, you're right :-) I see on the example you have "console.out.writeline" so for this should I have the project as "console application" or "winformapp"? 

In the console app I'm putting this into the "static void Main(string[] args)" correct? or am I totally off...?

Comment: You could use either. You can also just create a string instead of doing console.out (`string s = something`), even though a stringbuilder would be better, and just assign that string to your other textbox then.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm asking where exactly do I put this code at to get it to compile out so I can play around with it? Do I put it all after the "static void Main" inside the braces or before the namespace? If I put it inside the braces then I'm getting a lot of errors....hmm can you check my screenshot? http://oi42.tinypic.com/2vmvf2t.jpg

Comment: Glad I could have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your first `RichTextBox` has each item separated by something known (e.g. `NewLine`), then it should be as straight forward as this:

```
var list = richTextBox1.Text
    .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Sort();
richTextBox2.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.ToArray());
```

This will leverage the default sorting algorithm for the type. In this case `string`. So it will sort them alphabetically.